# Distinct pop when audio stops via bluetooth

Tags: sound, bluetooth

Whenever my laptop is connected to a bluetooth speaker and stops transmitting sound, a distinctive "pop" happens about 2-3 seconds after the sound stopped. It happens every single time sound stops. It is also very loud (no matter what volume you have on the computer).

Is there a setting to e.g. constantly transmit silence while connected (to prevent this), or is this just a bug that can be fixed? It is not limited to my current laptop model, it was the same with my last one as well.

Comment: It's probably something related to the speaker itself. Have you already tested in a different OS with different results?

Comment: Not recently, but afaik it does not happen in Windows 10. What I do know for a fact however, is that it does not happen when my friend's Macbook is connected. I'll test in Windows today or tomorrow.